# Which Crank Brothers cleat do I need?

Tags: pedals, cleat, replacement

I ride these pedals:

[image: Crank Brothers eggbeater pedal]

which came with these cleats:

[image: Stock crank brothers eggbeater cleat]

Now I see that Crank Brothers are selling their "Premium" cleat:

[image]

I'm ready to replace my cleats. Is the premium cleat compatible with my pedal, or do I need to stick to the earlier style? Do the 'wings' on the original cleat offer something that I need?

Answer (score 5):

To directly answer your question, yes, the Crank Bros Premium Cleat is the one you want.

Per their webiste -  compatibility: **eggbeater**, candy, smarty, acid, mallet ( http://www.crankbrothers.com/accessories_premium_cleat.php )

Some good FAQ on these from Crank Bros:
http://www.crankbrothers.com/support/faq_candy.php

Comment: Also this https://www.crankbrothers.com/blogs/news/cleats-customize-your-float-release-angle.  There are multiple versions of cleats that will work with that pedal depending on what adjustments and/or float level the rider wishes to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Premium cleats are a harder material, and will last longer than the cheaper brass cleats.

both fit the same, and both offer the 15 or 20 degree float option based on mount position.

Answer (score 1):

I talked with CB about the cleats that do not have the side to side adjustment ability and the answer was that early eggbeaters cleats had just two holes and no side to side adjustment and that was to save weight. So if you see cleats like that, they must be from a few years ago. But they work just as well. I am guessing they found out from rider feedback that some side to side adjustments where required depending on the shoes (wide or narrow sole) you had.

Answer (score 0):

The cleats and pedals I have look just like yours, except more used.
I love them.  I've used egg beaters on all my bikes for the last 5 years or so.  They shed dirt, they're easy and quiet to clip in and out, and except for one broken spring on an older pair, really reliable.

[image]

(FYI, some of the older eggbeaters didn't have wrench flats.  The ones in your picture do, but check before buying.)